# SICP Exercise 1.3: Sum of squares of two largest numbers out of three, Prolog Version

Tags: sicp, prolog

The exercise 1.3 of the book [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html) asks the following:

> Exercise 1.3.  Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers.

My answer is this:

```
squareTwoLargest(X, Y, Z, R) :- 
    ( X > Y -> A = X, B = Y ; A = Y, B = X ),
    R is A ^ 2 + max(B, Z) ^ 2.
```

My reason for learning Prolog is to understand the logic programming paradigm. So, how can I solve this exercise in good logic programming style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as stated, has a completely straight-forward solution, because the problem statement is limited to *numbers*:

```
sicp1(X, Y, Z, SumSquares) :-
        msort([X,Y,Z], [_,A,B]),
        SumSquares is A^2 + B^2.
```

You can use this predicate every time the three numbers are fully specified, for example:

```
?- sicp1(1, 2, 3, S).
S = 13.
```

The problem though is that this code is not as general as it could be. It does not work for example if the arguments are variables:

```
?- sicp1(X, Y, Z, S).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

From a truly declarative solution, we expect valid answers even if arguments are only partially known.

Enter *constraints*. I show you a solution with CLP(FD) constraints. This means that the arguments are elements of the set of *integers*. Check out other constraint libraries like CLP(Q) to get solutions over different domains.

Working solution for SICStus, SWI etc.:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sicp2(X, Y, Z, SumSquares) :-
        Max #= max(max(X, Y), Z),
        Median #= max(min(X, Y), min(max(X, Y), Z)),
        SumSquares #= Max^2 + Median^2.
```

Now, we can use this just like before:

```
?- sicp2(1, 2, 3, S).
S = 13.
```

*However*, we can also use it in other ways. For example:

```
?- sicp2(X, 3, 5, S).
...
S in 34..sup.
```

From this answer, you see that the sum of squares will be *at least* 34, no matter the eventual value of `X`.

When giving further constraints, you get more precise answers:

```
?- sicp2(X, 3, 5, S), X #< 4.
S = 34,
... .
```

This means that, if it is known that `X` is less than 4, then the result is *certainly* 34 in this case.

Thus, the solution using constraints is much more general, and it is just what we would expect from a truly declarative solution that can be queried in all directions and gives useful answers in all cases.

Comment: Wow, that's what I'm talking about! Just one thing: why does it say `Warning: Test is always true: var(Max); Test is always true: var(Median)` when I load the file?

Comment: Because you are not using a very recent version of SWI-Prolog. This superfluous warning has been fixed for more than 6 months already in the most recent development releases. Try 7.1.36, released today, for a more recent version.

Comment: @mat.  The goal `sort([1,1,1],[_,_,_])` fails, because it eliminates duplicates. You can use `msort/2` to keep the duplicates.

Comment: `[1,1,1]` cannot be considered valid input because which two numbers are then "the two larger numbers"? ;-)